# Definition of the "DFA for a language"

Tags: finite-automata

I just started learning Theory of Computation this semester and a bit confused by the phrase "DFA for a language". If it is asked to construct a  DFA for some collection of binary strings L, does it mean to find DFA M with L(M)=L or just $L(M)\supset L$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most compiler/theory courses tend to have different styles surrounding teaching definitions of deterministic finite automata and formal languages, but I'll try to make this description as agnostic as possible.

The phrase "DFA for a language" loosely means: a DFA which accepts every `word` in the language and rejects every `word` not in the language. 
The way I was taught DFAs is to have final/accepting states and regular states which removes the necessity for an implicit error state.
This means that a DFA accepts a word if the state it is in at the end of input is `accepting` and it rejects the word if the state is not `accepting`.

**Ex:**

Let's define L as the language which contains an even number of 1s. These will be binary strings so the symbols are just 0 and 1. 
`00`, `110`, <strike>`111`</strike>, `1111`, etc are examples of words in this language. Notice that the empty string is in this language.

We can have two states in our DFA. The starting state, let's call it `even 1s`, is also an accepting state because 0 ones is even. The other state is `odd 1s`, this is not accepting.

As for transitions, when `even 1s` receives a 1, it transitions to `odd 1s`. And when `odd 1s` receives a 1, it transitions to `even 1s`.
Now, the number of 0s doesn't matter, so in either state, it transitions to itself.

[image]

Apologies for the double arrow, this [website](http://madebyevan.com/fsm/) is great but I couldn't figure out how to separate the transitions between `even 1s` and `odd 1s`

Answer (score 1):

**Deterministic Finite Automaton (DFA)**
In DFA, for each input symbol, one can determine the state to which the machine will move. Hence, it is called Deterministic Automaton. As it has a finite number of states, the machine is called a Deterministic Finite Machine or Deterministic Finite Automaton.

**Formal Definition of a DFA**
A DFA can be represented by a 5-tuple (Q, ∑, δ, q0, F) where −

-> Q is a finite set of states.

-> ∑ is a finite set of symbols called the alphabet.

-> δ is the transition function where δ: Q × ∑ → Q

-> q0 is the initial state from where any input is processed (q0 ∈ Q).

-> F is a set of final state/states of Q (F ⊆ Q).

Answer (score 0):

Write your question in precise way. here DFA for a language means that you need to construct machine for particular language only not it's subset or superset. construct DFA maachine for which L(M)= L.